# Перебор массива

Tags: массивы, php, mysql

Есть ассоциированный массив, полученный с бд `$data['category']`.
В нем есть поле с created, то есть `$data['category']['created']`, где сохранено время в формате `1416490103`. И есть функция, которая эту строку чисел преобразует в нормальный формат 24-11-2014 или 11 октября 2014:

```
$this->category_model->rus_date($a);
```

`$a` отправляет в функцию `1416490103` и возвращает 11 октября 2014.

Задача такая: перебрать массив, перед тем как я его отправлю в шаблон, и получить уже `$result['category']`, где числа уже стоят в нормальном формате.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно же из MYSQL сразу вытягивать даты в нужном формате, зачем дополнительно обрабатывать уже полученные данные?

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT("2008-11-19",'%d.%m.%Y');
результат
19.11.2008
```

**Обновление**

Я просто задал вопрос о необходимости использования функции, ведь можно обойтись без нее и получать данные сразу в нужном формате.

По поводу вывода на необходимом языке: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lc_time_names

Для того, чтобы MySQL начала выводить даты на нужном нам языке — установите локаль, выполнив запрос:

```
SET lc_time_names = 'ru_RU';
```

Теперь попробуйте вывести текущую дату на родном нам языке:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%d %M %Y, %W') AS `date_ru`;
```

Результат: 29 Декабря 2013, Воскресенье

Comment: ОП упоминает определённую ф-ю, которую хочет задействовать для форматирования. А ешё покажите, как вытаскивать название месяца по-русски и по-немецки для некоторых посетителей сайта.

Comment: Я просто задал вопрос о необходимости использования функции.

По поводу вывода на необходимом языке:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lc_time_names

Для того, чтобы MySQL начала выводить даты на нужном нам языке — установите локаль, выполнив запрос:

SET lc_time_names = 'ru_RU';
Теперь попробуйте вывести текущую дату на родном нам языке:
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%d %M %Y, %W') AS `date_ru`;

Результат: 29 Декабря 2013, Воскресенье

Answer (score 1):

Правильно это делать в шаблоне. rus_date - должен быть хелпером шаблонизатора. Это позволит вам уже на  месте манипулировать так, как захотите, и не придется делать двойную работу.

Comment: А можно подробней...

Answer (score 1):

Функция php [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-map.php) поможет пройтись по всему массиву, применяя к каждому элементу функцию, которая будет заменять время в секундах на текстовую строку. Как-то так:

```
function secToDate( $e) {
    $e['created'] = $this->category_model->rus_date( $e['created']);
}
$result['category'] = array_map( array( $this, 'secToDate'), $data['category']);
```